# Duplicate the same value in column level using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, duplicates

I have a CSV file as shown below. I need to achieve to duplicate the same value in column level using unix shell command. data as shown below

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8... 
aaaa,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,12-jan-2018,
bbbb,14-jan-2018,
cccc,15-jan-2018,
```

I need to convert the CSV file to look like below

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8... 
aaaa,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,14-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
cccc,15-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
```

However, the first 3 column will always have a value from the 1st file and remaining columns need to be duplicated with the 1st row of the 2nd file.

Comment: Is it the line with `ddd,10` always the first line?

Comment: yes, its always the first line.. Here, I am merging the 2 CSV files, 1 file has only single row and the other has multiple rows. So I used paste -d to merge them. but I need to duplicate the records matching the count of the 1st file rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script like this can do the work:

```
awk -F\, 'NR==1 {a=$3"," $4;print } NR!=1 {print $0""a}' input.file
```

To have more columns you can add them to awk on such way

```
awk -F\, 'NR==1 {a=$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9;print } NR!=1 {print $0""a}' input.file
```

Comment: Its working fine, but limited upto the 4th column, but I have additional 6 more columns which need to be duplicated. as below

aaaa,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,12-jan-2018,
bbbb,14-jan-2018,
cccc,15-jan-2018,


aaaa,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,12-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
bbbb,14-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy
cccc,15-jan-2018,ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy

Comment: @in such case edit your questions with precise details

Comment: I have edit the question again to have precise detail.

Comment: @Raam, in such case feel free to upvode/accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the command paste (replace `INPUT.csv` with your filename):

`paste <(cat INPUT.csv | cut -f 1,2 -d "," ) <(for l in $(cat INPUT.csv); do echo "ddd,10,5,6,sample,xxx,yyyy"; done) -d ","`

The `for` loop is required to add the same number of rows, however, I believe there may be other alternatives.

Also, you can replace the echo with a `cat | cut | head` pipe to get the elements in the first row you are interested, something like:

`paste <(cat INPUT.csv | cut -f 1,2 -d "," ) <(for l in $(cat INPUT.csv); do cat INPUT.csv | cut -f 3-9 -d "," | head -n 1; done) -d ","`

Or simply merge both files at once (replace `INPUT_1.CSV` and `INPUT_2.CSV` accordingly):

`paste <(cat INPUT_1.csv | cut -f 1,2 -d "," ) <(for l in $(cat INPUT_1.csv); do cat INPUT_2.csv; done) -d ","`